# Prove that $\gamma^\Omega$ is larger than $\Omega^\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\Omega$ is the omega constant

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, reference-request, lambert-w, euler-mascheroni-constant

In this post we denote the Euler-Mascheroni constant as $\gamma$ and the known as omega constant as $\Omega=W(1)$ with $W(x)$ the main/principal branch of the Lambert $W$ function. I don't know if the following problem is in the literature (if you know it from the literature please add a comment).

> **Question.** Provide a simple reasoning to prove that $\gamma^\Omega$ is larger than $\Omega^\gamma$. **Many thanks.**

I know that similar problems are in the literature, but I don't know if precisely this is in the literature. If you know it add the reference or a comment, and I try to search and read those reasoning from the literature. My belief is that previous constants $\Omega^\gamma$ and $\gamma^\Omega$ aren't in the OEIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^{1/x}$ has a maximum at $x=e$ with e as euler‘s number. (can be shown by taking the derivative of the function)
[image]
Because the function is increasing before and decreasing after $x=e$, if x and y are two real numbers, which are bigger than 0 and $x<y$, than if x and y are smaller than e:
$$x^{1/x}<y^{1/y}$$
Raise it to the power of $xy$.
$$x^y<y^x$$
This holds true because x and y are positive numbers.

In your case the two numbers are smaller than e, so this proof applies.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: I removed the link and wrote out the proof.